# Inner join query logic

Tags: sql-server

I am using Sql Server Management studio.

I have the following table.

[image]

when i run the following query I get the running total for **sales column**

```
select s1.date,
sum(s2.sales)
from sales s1
join sales s2 on s1.date>=s2.date
group by s1.date;
```

but when i **substitute s2.sales with s1.sales** in the select

```
select s1.date,
**sum(s1.sales)**
from sales s1
join sales s2 on s1.date>=s2.date
group by s1.date;
```

it gives me a different answer can someone help me understand why i am facing this? since the sales column value should be the same.

Comment: Are you really using Sql Server 2005? As in, 16 years old and no longer supported? Not even for security patches? If so, that's dangerous and irresponsible.

Comment: No, I am not, I have re-edited the post. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: don't tag `mysql` if you're using SQL Server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first version of your running total query is summing sales, for each dates, over dates which are strictly less than or equal to the date in each record.  When you change `s2.sales` to `s1.sales`, you are then summing the current record's sales N number of times, where N is the number of records having an earlier date.  This clearly is not the logic you want, so stick with the first version.

By the way, if you're using MySQL 8+, then analytic functions simplify things even further:

```sql
SELECT Date, Sales, SUM(Sales) OVER (ORDER BY Date) RunningSales
FROM sales
ORDER BY Date;
```